# How to search through thousands of files to text efficiently in real-time

Tags: c#, sql-server, full-text-search

I'm working on refactoring a document storage service's site to go from a proprietary storage system to SQL.  Everything is going fairly well, but I need to find a way to search through our repository for specific strings of text.  We use a multitude of different file types (.xls,.xlsx,.doc,.txt, etc).  They're displayed to the user by first converting them to a PDF, via line-by-line rebuilding using PDFSharp.

The speed isn't a consideration for viewing/searching a single file, but I have concerns about scalability.  I was able to make a functioning text search by copying and then hooking into our conversion process, but I am fairly sure that this will not work for searching through a customer's entire document list (thousands and thousands of documents).  If these were all of a uniform file type, it might be easier to do, but they aren't.

Is there an efficient way to do this of which I am unaware?

EDIT:  The documents are stored on the server and referenced via document URLs in the DB

Comment: You are aware of full text search capabilities in SQL Server? You tried them out?

Comment: I am not.  I have looked into full-text searching, but our files are not stored as text files, so I don't know if SQL server could index the files(they have to be converted first).

And this is purely a point of ignorance, but wouldn't full-text indexing require storing the entire thing in text on the database?  And how would I get the page numbers from that?

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me.   You have files in a proprietary format, and what?   you need to import them into SQL in "real time"?   I can't imagine any scenario that would require this, so I must be misunderstanding your need.

Comment: @NicholasMansfield, to utilize text-search, you don't need to have TEXT format, SQL Server cna process all Office documents, PDF and some more. so you even don't need to convert your files to text.

Comment: @Tab The files are not in a proprietary format, our old DB system is.  That means that I can't just use their algorithms.

Comment: Well that helps to clear up what your question is not, at least.   Still have no idea what your question IS.

Comment: @Tab  I don't need to import them.  I need to search them.  A basic use case is that a customer wants to see the transaction details for order number 101567.  They don't know in which document the sale line is or where in the file it will be.  So they search 101567, and it should return a list of documents and the respective page/line,etc.

My problem is that I don't know how to effectively search the information.  I can't just put everything into the database, since that would massively inflate the size of the DB.

Comment: So, in what way is SQL involved in this question?

Comment: @Tab The documents are retrieved via links stored in SQL, and from what I understand, there is a way to handle this using SQL indexing.

Comment: No, you were right in your first comment.  SQL indexing is for when you have the data stored as text in the database.  And if you did that, using Out Of The Box SQL indexing, you wouldn't be able to get page numbers.  To do that you'll need to build a custom index, as I suggest in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to build an index, either in SQL or in a file.   One that matches files with all the possible search terms of interest in each file.

Comment: How would I know what terms are of interest/  Just not include all words on a list ("the, an, ' ' , etc)?

Comment: That's a business rule question that I can't possibly know the answer to.   Having a black list (all words except these) or white list (only these words) is definitely one way to handle it from a development perspective though.

Comment: Thank you.  That helps out.